# Functions Predeploy Errors - Endless Function Naming Issues

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am having trouble deploying my Firebase function, as I can't seem to name my function by ANY standard. I wanted to name my function "mgHandleStripePaymentSuccess".

Here is my code (this is the entire function)

```
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();

// Import the onCustomEventPublished function from Eventarc
import {onCustomEventPublished} from "firebase-functions/v2/eventarc";

export const mgHandleStripePaymentSuccess = onCustomEventPublished(
  "com.stripe.v1.checkout.session.completed",
  (event: any) => {
    console.log("Stripe payment success event data:", event.data);
    // Handle extension event here.
    return null;
  });
```

Here are my errors:

```
Error: mgHandleStripePaymentSuccess v2 function name(s) can only contain lower case letters, numbers, hyphens, and not exceed 62 characters in length
```

I renamed my function "mg-handle-stripe-payment-success" to use only lowercase letters and hyphens, as it stated I could. Again, another error

```
12:15  error  Parsing error: ',' expected
```

Line 12, character 15, is the location of the first hyphen in the function name. At this point, I thought maybe it mixed up hyphens for underscores? I tested this by changing my function name to "mg_handle_stripe_payment_success" and got the worst error of all:

```
12:14  error    Identifier 'mg_handle_stripe_payment_success' is not in camel case  camelcase
```

The first error stated that I couldn't use camelCase. So, do I have to name my function in the most terrible way possible? Such as:

"mghandlestripepaymentsuccess"?

Considering that the Firebase Stripe Extension made their functions all lowercase with hyphens, I think something is bugged (on my end or the linter)

[image]

Comment: Very much against my will, I changed the function name to "handlesuccess" so I can move on with my testing. butijustwantedtosaythatthisiscompletelyterribleandiabsolutlyhateit. LOL, sorry - but please help me.

Comment: This limitation has changed. See the update to my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gen 2 Cloud Functions used to have [restrictions on function names](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta#other_limitations):

> Function names are restricted to lowercase letters and numbers.

This limitation has been lifted as of [April 4th 2023](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/release-notes#April_04_2023):

> You can now use uppercase letters and underscores in the function name you specify for a 2nd gen function when you deploy the function.

This is further elaborated upon in the [deployment documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy#basics)

> The first argument, `YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME`, is a name for your deployed function. The function name must start with a letter followed by up to 62 letters, numbers, hyphens, or underscores, and must end with a letter or a number.

Comment: I really appreciate the update! The lowercase-only letter convention wasn't fun to work with at all.